# How to obtain the shared secret key?

Tags: authentication, cryptography, smartcard

I am trying to perform external authentication on smart card, but it needs shared secret key to perform encryption on challenge. How to obtain the shared secret key from the card.
Thanks in advace

Comment: Nowhere near enough information in this question to answer it. What type of smart card? What API are you using? What language?

Comment: takumar is right. To obtain the secret key you need to ask the issuer of the card, or know a lot on DPA attacks and/or other related and applicable side channel attacks, of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point with using smart cards is that you can't get the secret. Only the card an the card issuer know it.

Comment: Without knowing the shared secret key how can i perform external authentication with my program ?

Comment: You can't. In an external auth, the typical sequence is that you get the challenge from the card, compute the adequate response, and then send the result is the external auth command, so that subsequently you are authenticated by the card as a legit user to perform some tasks. You need to elaborate on what you try to achieve, what type card you use, in which context. If you use a test card, you should be able to find out the secret (on test cards they are not real secrets). If you use some sort of production card, you need to ask the issue for the secret.